# How to send stream closure with XMPPFramework

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework

I am developing a chat App using XMPPFramework and I ran into trouble when trying to close the stream.

I have stream management enabled on my Ejabberd server and I would like to use APNS to send notification while the client monitor is switched off or App is in the background. I call the below function every time while the app is going to background.

```
func disconnect() {        
    goOffline() // send unavailable presence
    self.stream.disconnect()
}
```

Unfortunately, the connection is not immediately terminated as stream management is enabled. And all messages were lost during the time the stream is still active.

According to [XEP-0198](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html#closure) documentation, a `</stream:stream>` must be sent to close the stream, how may I do that? or should I use another approach to handle this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any problem here.  Try implement delegate `xmppStreamDidDisconnect` or `xmppStreamDidSendClosingStreamStanza` see if you can get anything back?

Comment: I realize that the problem is not caused by the disconnecting the stream. It is because I create a new stream every time when trying to reconnect to the server so that a new session will be created instead of resuming to the last session. Thanks.